# I need to customize the length of the print

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
key_one = int(input("Enter key (0 <= key <= 127): "))

if key_one in range(128):
    bin_key_one = f'{key_one:07b}'
    print(bin_key_one)
else:
    print("You have to enter key (0 <= key <= 127)")
```

like If I entered in key_one 3 I need the print length equal to 3

Comment: can you add an input example and the expected output ?

Comment: can't understand your comment, for ex if the input is 120, what should be the print output?

Comment: also if the input is 0 what should be the output?

Comment: @kederrac  if the input was 5 I need the binary digit equal to 5

Comment: what about 120 and 0 ?

Comment: @kederrac  its just putting example of my work what I need to know is how if I entered a number in key_one I need the print length equal to the number I entered

Comment: you didn't provide an example of the output,  for 120 you want 120 digits ?

Comment: @kederrac how can I show you my work to get what I am doing please that will make it clear

Comment: for ex, for 5, what should be the output ? just one example will be enough

Comment: 5 ? '101' ? '00000101'

Comment: @kederrac I need to add four leading zeros to the binary out put if u add it to the binary of 5 is 0000101 this is 7 digits I need it 5 this is an example

Comment: but your code is already doing this

Comment: @kederrac if I put 5 he will give me 7 digits in output

Comment: ok. but for 120 you want 120 characters in the output ?

Comment: @kederrac yes 120

Comment: @kederrac did you get it

Comment: @kederrac can you help me with something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can just use:

```
key_one = int(input("Enter key (0 <= key <= 127): "))

if key_one in range(128):
    bin_key_one = f'{key_one:0{int(key_one)}b}'
    print(bin_key_one)
else:
    print("You have to enter key (0 <= key <= 127)")
```

output:

```
Enter key (0 <= key <= 127): 5
00101
```